# Direct2D widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace == 0 while width > 0?

Tags: msdn, directwrite

An issue with Microsoft's Direct2D framework.

How is it possible that `width > widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace`? Shouldn't it be

`width == widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace`

in the case of **no trailing spaces** and

`width < widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace`.

when the underlying string **contains trailing spaces**?

In my case the underlying string is "   Info ". It has a trailing space in it and still the  `widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace` is zero. See screenshot:

[image]

[MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ns-dwrite-dwrite_text_metrics?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(DWRITE%252FDWRITE_TEXT_METRICS);k(DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) states:

> `width`
>
> Type: FLOAT
>
> A value that indicates the width of the formatted text, while ignoring
> trailing whitespace at the end of each line.
>
> `widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace`
>
> Type: FLOAT
>
> The width of the formatted text, taking into account the trailing whitespace at the end of each line.

Comment: I had the same issue, so I just added a test if widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace < width then widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace = width... Looks like a bug to me, this was I a big program, but IMHO you should report that to Microsoft if you have an easy reproductible test.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a MSDN bug.

The issue occurs only with

```
IDWriteTextLayout->SetTextAlignment(DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TRAILING)
```

In the case of

```
IDWriteTextLayout->SetTextAlignment(DWRITE_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEADING)
```

the `widthIncludingTrailingWhitespace` is calculated correctly.